# Dynamic colspan in Angular

Tags: html, angular, html-table

The number of bands and antennas are dynamic. I need this data to be shown in a table.

```
active_bands_to_antennas = [
 {
   band: "Blue",
   antennas: ["One", "Two" "Three"]
},
{
   band: "Red",
   antennas: ["Four", Five"]
} 
]
```

**Template:**

```
<tr>
  <th>&nbsp</th>
  <th *ngFor="let data of active_bands_to_antennas" [attr.colspan]="data.antennas.length">{{data.band}}</th>
  <th>&nbsp</th>
  <th>&nbsp</th>
</tr>
```

**Expected Output:**

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td colspan="3">Blue</td>
    <td colspan="2">Red</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
    <td>Four</td>
    <td>Five</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
    <td>&nbsp</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Everything is working as it should. Except that the bands are showing in multiple rows instead of only one (depending on the number of bands).

**Current Output:**

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
        <td colspan="3">Blue</td>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
        <td colspan="2">Red</td>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>Five</td>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
      </tr
    </table>
```

This is where I got the idea to implement "*colspan*": [Dynamic rowspan in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53406725/dynamic-rowspan-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired output one possible way is to create 'array of arrays' from `antennas` property.

```
const arrayOfArrays = this.active_bands_to_antennas.map((x) => x.antennas);
```

After this you will get an array = [ ['One', 'Two', 'Three'], ['Four', 'Five'] ];

Then you can flatten this to get an one dimensional array: ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']

HTML is basically two loops one for header and one for antennas.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp</th>
    <th
      *ngFor="let band of active_bands_to_antennas"
      [attr.colspan]="band.antennas.length"
    >
      {{ band.band }}
    </th>
    <th>&nbsp</th>
    <th>&nbsp</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td *ngFor="let ant of antennas">
      {{ ant }}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-v9syw5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)